# Alternative to sed -i that does not write temporary files

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed, replace

I have several scripts that edit template text files, by removing a "tag" and replacing it with e.g. a number. To do this I use the

```
sed -i
```

command. However, I have an issue with write/read times on the server where I execute the scripts, making the scripts take a long time to run, since the sed -i command writes a temporary file to disk for every execution.

Is there an alternative approach that I could use, where a temporary file is not written to disk for every single replacement? Can the text file be edited in the memory and only written once all the replacements have been executed, or could I stack several replacements into the same sed command?

To clarify, the script is of the following form:

```
input=shiftLeft.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
    sed -i "s/install, element = $line, at=/install, element = $line, at= -0.001 +/g" processedFiles/layoutDB.seq
done < "$input"
```

That is, I read values from one text file, and then I do some changes in another text file depending on these values. This is done repeatedly for a large number of values.

Comment: Please add at least one script you are using.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't simply use `ed`?

Comment: "_could I stack several replacements into the same sed command?_" suggests that you're repeatedly running `sed -i` on the same file.  Yes, you should add all the `-e` commands you want into a single `sed` invocation (or even into a `sed` script file - see `sed -f`).

Comment: @TobySpeight `ed` would potentially also use temporary files.

Comment: `sed -i` does not take a long time to run due to creating temporary files. It takes a long time to run because you're executing it in a tight loop.  Please show what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do not know about ed. I will have a look at sed -e and -f. The script is slow due to the writing of temporary files. The file system is based on another server, and due to often heavy loads, reading and writing can be very slow at times. Even a simple thing such as doing "mkdir" on this system can sometimes take several seconds. Running the script locally, it is sometimes a hundred times faster.

Comment: Both seds I tried, the GNU and Busybox ones write a new file and then rename that on top of the original. Which means they don't write a temporary file, just the new file, though since they allocate a new inode, it will mean allocating new blocks for the data. But you can't get over the fact that (in the general case) they need to rewrite the whole file, since the line length could change (and seems to definitely do in your case). So yes, if you make N one-line changes to a K block file in sequence, you end up writing N*K blocks of data.

Comment: @a20, if the problem is that the remote FS is slow (which will depend a lot on how much local caching the FS and its settings allow), then the obvious solution is not use it. Make all the changes locally, e.g. in `/tmp` and then copy the file in place in the background (making sure to take care of any necessary locking, i.e. that another process isn't also changing the file at the same time. Or instead of repeatedly running `sed` on the whole file, build one set of sed commands and run it against the file once.

Comment: @ilkkachu indeed, doing everything outside of this server and then just copying the result is a workaround, but it is not very convenient, especially since it is not just a one-time thing. I would therefore prefer a solution that just writes the new file once, after having done all the necessary changes in the memory.

Comment: Have you tracked (e.g. with `strace`) the creation of temporary files?  I would expect `sed -i` to create and write exactly one file (the new output file), which shouldn't be a major overhead.  Except that you're running multiple invocations on the same file.

Comment: @TobySpeight no I have not tracked it, but I can see in realtime that it creates a bunch of sedXXXXXX files in the same folder. These files are eventually removed, but not immediately, so I guess that it copies these files into the original file name, rather than changing the name as suggested by above

Comment: @Kusalananda the `ed` on my Debian doesn't create a temporary; it runs in memory and the `w` command writes to the original file (tested using `strace -efile ed /tmp/foo <<<wq`).  This allows it to edit files in read-only directories and on nearly-full filesystems/quotas, but requires more process memory and risks losing data if the process dies during the write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't that `sed -i` creates many temporary files, it's that you're running it many times with the same input file, and each of those creates a temporary file for the output, as `strace` shows:

```
execve("/bin/sed", ["sed", "-i", "-e", "", "/tmp/foo"], 0x7fff10da5288 /* 36 vars */) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/foo", O_RDONLY)  = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/sedVdjaBk", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
rename("/tmp/sedVdjaBk", "/tmp/foo")    = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The solution is to run `sed -i` just once.

To do that, start by writing a `sed` command that transforms your input file into a `sed` program.  That would look something like:

```sh
sed -e 's!.*!s/install, element = &, at=/install, element = &, at= -0.001 +/g!"
```

(It's possible that we could improve this, if the input file includes regex-significant characters, e.g. `s/install, element = &, at=/\& -0.001 +/g`, but that's outside the scope of this question).

Test this to ensure you're happy with the resultant script.

Then we need to get another `sed` to use that transformed text as its program file.  We can do that by telling it to read its program from standard input (although there are alternatives¹):

```sh
sed -e 's!.*!s/install, element = &, at=/install, element = &, at= -0.001 +/g!' \
    shiftLeft.txt |
sed -f - -i processedFiles/layoutDB.seq
```

Again, test this (without the `-i` flag) until you're satisfied it does what you want it to.

---

¹
Since we're using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), we can use a process substitution:

```sh
sed -f <(sed -e 's!.*!s/install, element = &, at=/install, element = &, at= -0.001 +/g!' shiftLeft.txt) \
    -i processedFiles/layoutDB.seq
```

In standard shell, we'd need to capture the transformed text as a string, and supply that as a command-line script:

```sh
sed -e "$(sed -e 's!.*!s/install, element = &, at=/install, element = &, at= -0.001 +/g!' shiftLeft.txt)" \
    -i processedFiles/layoutDB.seq
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since I have multiple loops, I output sed -e result to a file for all the sed replacements I need to do. I then call this output file using sed -i -f tempSed.sed targetFile.txt . Currently the server is not under heavy load, yet, with my old approach it took 127.448 seconds, whereas with your suggestion it only takes 5.623 seconds. Running it locally the speed improvement was from 3.848s to 3.522s.

Comment: @a20, you can probably combine the multiple loops without needing a temporary file: `(loop1; loop2; loop3) | sed -f -`.  (OTOH, if you like a file, then put it somewhere local, such as in `"${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/"`).

Comment: The best way to find a good local location for your file is to use `tmpfile`, of course (don't forget to set a `trap` so it's removed even if your script exits early).

Answer (score 3):

Don't call sed repeatedly in a shell loop, just call awk once, e.g. (untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output to test with) using GNU awk for "inplace" editing and the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk -i inplace '
    NR==FNR { lines[$0] }
    (FNR>NR) && match($0,/(.*install, element = )([^,]+)(, at=)/,a) && (a[2] in lines) {
        $0 = a[0] " -0.001 +"
    }
    { print }
' shiftLeft.txt processedFiles/layoutDB.seq
```

There may be a better way to do that depending on what your input/output looks like.

Comment: Thank you! The above answer worked for me, but it is very nice to know of alternative methods.